# s3 started returning premature end of content-length errors using Apache Spark while working fine on an older EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

We are using S3 buckets as dataset store for our datasets, where the data is stored as parquet files.

We are running Apache Spark on AWS r6g instances that have Hydrosphere Mist as a proxy to start jobs in Spark instances. We use a local cluster mode, so each instance runs spark workers in docker containers. 4 days ago one of our EC2 instances suddenly started giving end of content-length errors when reading a parquet files from the bucket, while another instance read them just fine. The next day, however, both running instances started giving that error. Recreating them also didn't help, the issue didnt go away and happens on each job run that reads data from our S3 bucket.

The error is as follows:

```
Error: RSocket error 0x201 (APPLICATION_ERROR): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1977131; received: 849
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:172)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.abort(S3ObjectInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.seek(S3AInputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H1SeekableInputStream.seek(H1SeekableInputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1157)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The versions that we are on:

- spark - 2.4.4
- hydrosphere mist - 1.1.3
- hadoop - 2.7
- java aws sdk - 1.7.4 (hadoop 2.7 uses the same version)
- jvm - 1.8

We use `s3a://` to read the S3 bucket and are using the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` s3a implementation.

I think that one of the possible problems could be the Java AWS SDK version, since 1.7.4 is a really old and now currently supported version, but Spark gives 2.7 as its main Hadoop version, so that *shouldn't* be the issue.

The datasets themselves are quite small, all are below 10mb right now.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

edit1: the content lengths that it fails on tend to be the same, they arent random. So its always 849, 7744, 664 or 8192. This depends on the specific job. Removing compression from parquet files also changed the smallest number from 696 to 849.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: NOT fixed. The issue persists. However, it turns out that running spark and mist locally does not produce this issue.

Newer Hadoop 2.7 builds actually dont use aws-java-sdk 1.7.4. Updating to a more recent Spark version that comes with a more recently built Hadoop fixed the issue. We're now on Spark 3.0.1 and Hadoop 2.7.4.

Another issue was that we included both org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk dependencies. The second can safely be removed. After that things are working smoothly again

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue was due to Hadoop 2.7. After upgrading to Hadoop 3.2 the issue has been solved. Also note to others to make sure you dont have conflicting guava dependencies (should be version 27-jre, although I removed this dependency completely as I didn't need it) or the wrong hadoop-aws version. The hadoop-aws dependency version must be 3.2, cant be 3.2.1 or anything else.

Comment: 3.2.0 worked while 2.7.4 was giving premature end of content length, Thanks!